# SSIS OLEDB data transfer calling parametereized stored procedure | Columns not found

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb

I have a SQL server stored procedure which takes as parameter a part of the database name. It works perfectly when executing from SQL Server Management Studio.

However I need to call this SP from SSIS OLE DB Source component. When I specify the SQL command and parameters in the OLE DB Source component, I get the following error:

> "Error at  SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has
>   occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server does
>   not contain the table  The table either does not exist or the current
>   user does not have permissions on that table.".: Unable to retrieve
>   column information from the data source. Make sure your target table
>   in the database is available".

Basically it cant find the table used by the stored procedure as the database name is parameterized. I searched around and found that OLE DB data source needs meta data for the table. How can I provide this?

This is my stored procedure:

```
USE [ILLP]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OUTPUT_MI_Tyep12] @param1 varchar(5)
AS
BEGIN
    SET FMTONLY OFF;
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @query varchar(1000)

set @query='
SELECT [M12]
      ,[T3Size]
      ,[SizeVCost]
      ,NULL as [DefaultTonnage]
      ,NULL as [IdleCost]
      ,NULL as [SuperLocoID]
      ,[IfAllowFleetSizeVio]
  FROM [ServN\PROD2].[Scenario_' + @param1 +'_PRD].[dbo].[Para_LTYPE]'

exec(@query)
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are trying to loop through different databases using the SP with a parameter in SSIS. However you could do this with a Select Command From variable source:

1. Create a new Variable - `SELECT_OUTPUT_MI_Tyep12` for instance (String Type);
2. Within the variable properties check `EvaluateAsExpression = True`;
3. Under the Expression use the following:

   ```
   SELECT [M12]
         ,[T3Size]
         ,[SizeVCost]
         ,NULL as [DefaultTonnage]
         ,NULL as [IdleCost]
         ,NULL as [SuperLocoID]
         ,[IfAllowFleetSizeVio] 
   FROM [ServN\\PROD2].[Scenario_" + @[User::DBNameParameter]  + "_PRD].[dbo].[Para_LTYPE]
   ```
4. Change the `@[User::DBNameParameter]` for your specific one;
5. Use the SQL Command from variable in the connection manager, selecting the `SELECT_OUTPUT_MI_Tyep12` variable.

This should allow you to gather all the Meta data back from the table and carry on with the rest of the data flow.